# Not able to display all values in an html table

Tags: javascript, html

For unknown reasons to me I cannot display the last (`sProductLink`) value in this table :

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I cannot see any reason for this issue. The html is the same as for the other elements.
Whne I look in the DOM I don't see the "Link" `<td>` at all, which means it is not added for some reason.

Here is the code for this. I will really appreciate if someone has a look at this.

```
  $("#lblEditDeleteProducts").append('<tr><th class="idDom" scope="row">'
    +sProductId+"<span data-i-user-id='"
    +sProductId+"'</span>"
    +"<button type='button' id='editBtn' class='btn btn-warning editBtn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Edit</button>"
    + "<button id='deleteBtn' class='btn btn-danger deleteBtn'>Delete</button>"
    +'</th><td class="nameDom">'
    +sProductName+'</td><td class="brandDom">'
    +sProductBrand+'</td><td class="priceDom">'
    +sProductPrice+'</td><td class="linkDom">'
    +sProductLink+'</td></tr>');
```

P.S. I'd also appreciate any tips on how can I do what I am doing here in an alternative(better) way. Without all the apostrophes and etc.

Comment: Does javascript console tell you anything?

Comment: The value is there when I console.log it.

Comment: *"Without all the apostrophes and etc."*, you could at least start with being consistent about matching `'` and `"`. It would be a lot less confusing. But the better approach is to use any of the various libraries that provide data binding

Comment: What does the generated HTML actually look like?

Comment: Your tags are mangled right here `"<span data-i-user-id='"  +sProductId+"'</span>"` That first `<span` doesn't have an ending `>`

Comment: If your HTML includes your JQuery command "$("#lblEditDeleteProducts").append..." before your body tag, you may face this problem, I suggest you include the script tag that contains this like at the end of the body, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your string:

```
"<span data-i-user-id='" +sProductId+"'</span>"
```

Should probably be:

```
"<span data-i-user-id='" +sProductId+"'></span>"
```

This is why building HTML via string concatenation is a colossal pain.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this, but the problem still persists.

Comment: can you delete or archive my question. I don't think it helps the community much.

Answer (score 1):

In the area where the skull  is indicating, there's no *greater than bracket* `>` to close the inside of the `<span>`.

```
$("#lblEditDeleteProducts").append(
'<tr>
  <th class="idDom" scope="row">'+sProductId+'
  <span data-i-user-id="'+sProductId+'"</span>
  <button type="button" id="editBtn" class="btn btn-warning editBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Edit
  </button>
  <button id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger deleteBtn">
  Delete
  </button>
  </th>
  <td class="nameDom">'+sProductName+'</td>
  <td class="brandDom">'+sProductBrand+'</td>
  <td class="priceDom">'+sProductPrice+'</td>
  <td class="linkDom">'+sProductLink+'</td>
  </tr>');
```

#### SNIPPET

```js
var sProductId = 'sProd01';
var sProductName = 'sProExtreme';
var sProductBrand = 'sPro™';
var sProductPrice = 54.99;
var sProductLink = 'http://shop.spro.com';

$("#lblEditDeleteProducts").append('<tr><th class="idDom" scope="row">' + sProductId + '<span data-i-user-id="' + sProductId + '"></span><button type="button" id="editBtn" class="btn btn-warning editBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button><button id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger deleteBtn">Delete</button></th><td class="nameDom">' + sProductName + '</td><td class="brandDom">' + sProductBrand + '</td><td class="priceDom">' + sProductPrice + '</td><td class="linkDom">' + sProductLink + "</td></tr>");
```

```css
table {
  border: 5px inset orange;
}
tr {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
th {
  border: 5px dashed green;
  color: yellow;
}
td {
  border: 2px inset blue;
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/fontawesome@4.6.3,bootstrap@3.3.7(css/bootstrap.min.css+css/bootstrap-theme.min.css)">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="lblEditDeleteProducts"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you write the HTML that you're trying to append inside an editor, spaced out so you can see the structure properly and debug from there. You can minify it afterwards and test to ensure that it's in working order.

```
    <tr>
        <th class="idDom" scope="row">
            + sProductId +
            <span data-i-user-id='"+sProductId+"'><!-- Closing '>' added (Thanks Matt) --></span>
            <button type='button' id='editBtn' class='btn btn-warning editBtn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
                Edit
    </button>
            <button id='deleteBtn' class='btn btn-danger deleteBtn'>
                Delete
            </button>
        </th>
        <td class="nameDom">
            + sProductName +
        </td>
        <td class="brandDom">
            + sProductBrand +
        </td>
        <td class="priceDom">
            + sProductPrice +
        </td>
        <td class="linkDom">
            + sProductLink +
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Dont forget the `""` marks around your HTML